# How can I reduce the size of AspNet.ApplicationCookie and what's in it?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies

In our production environment (only) any Admin account has a good chance of receiving "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long." on just about any request.  Looking at the cookies I see that the AspNet.ApplicaitonCookie is huge, 15K.  In our other environments this cookie is about 1K.  This is a fairly new issue (been live over 2 years) and I'm told there were no changes made in the days prior.

What is in this cookie? (aside from 'authentication stuff')

What can I do to reduce it's size?

What could cause prod to be so different?  Theoretically it should be the same as staging but it's clearly not.

I'd prefer to "fix" this cookie instead of changing the size limits.  I always prefer fixing the issue instead of covering it up.

Comment: perhaps you should consider another method of storing data besides cookies..

Comment: What is in the cookie?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with web dev, our regular guy is on vacation for another 3 weeks.  If I knew what was in the cookie I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: That cookie is used by OWIN to store 'authentication stuff`, if only admins are having this problem then the admin role must have something in it which makes to grow the cookie. Think what are the last changes done to the admin role, that may give you a hint.

Comment: Supposedly there have been no changes.   What info about the admin roll is in there?

Comment: Check the admin identity claims, all those are stored in that cookie

Comment: What's the easiest way to see those?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is in this cookie? (aside from 'authentication stuff')

All the user Identity stuff.  Including anything that may have been put in via custom Claims.

> What can I do to reduce it's size?

Remove some of the custom Claims.

> What could cause prod to be so different?

Data!!  Prod has way more data than Dev.

So apparently who ever wrote this particular gem didn't know (or didn't care) that the claim data got stuffed into a cookie and passed around.  'They' put a list in there that will grow with time.  Removed and solved.