# How to reduce cookie size in ASP.NET Core (something similar to using reference mode)?

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, session-cookies

I am implementing an ASP.NET Core web application that uses cookie and WS-Federation authentication (it uses the cookie if it's there and works, otherwise it asks the identity provider for a SAML token if the user is signed in).

I have this set up fine in a Web API project in .NET. For cookie authentication, I use `System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule` to help. More specifically, it has the `IsReferenceMode` property which I set to true, thus allowing the cookie to be stored in a server-side cache throughout the session. This allows just a reference to the cookie to be passed between the client and server which helps reduce the size of the cookie.

Obviously this is not directly supported in ASP.NET Core since `System.IdentityModel` is incompatible. I'm wondering if there's something similar I can do.

I've seen similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504013/reducing-identity-cookie-size-in-net-core-2-0?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575865/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-aspnet-applicationcookie-and-whats-in-it), but neither really help me.

Edit: [This article on session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x) from the Microsoft docs and [this blog article](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/20/cookie-size-and-cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) by Jan Hajek seem like they could provide an answer for me.

Comment: did you explored around cookie chunking

Comment: Oh, I found [an article](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/20/cookie-size-and-cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-core/) that may be useful for me.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48661052/cannot-pass-complex-object-to-another-action-method help?

Comment: @Drew could you consider accepting the one-and-only answer? ✌

Comment: Yes sorry, I must have never looked at this again. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple MemoryCacheTicketStore that implements ITicketStore and configure your cookie like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
.AddIdentityCookies(options => options.ApplicationCookie.Configure(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.SessionStore = new MemoryCacheTicketStore(ApplicationSettings.Current.AuthenticationTimeOut);
    })
);
```

This is taken from a GitHub sample, [please have a look at it](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/beaa2b443d46ef8adaf5c2a89eb475e1893037c2/samples/CookieSessionSample).